# Core graphics drawing on a UIView inside a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, core-graphics

I have a `UIView` (viewA) on top of a `UIScrollView` (scrollView). I have my drawing code in the `drawRect` of viewA. In the view controller, I set the content size of the scroll view to the size of width = 1200 and height = 300 (defined as constant). When I add these views using storyboard, the width is 288. I change the frame size of viewA in the `initWithCoder` method. Based on `NSLog`, the `frame.size.width` is set to 1200.

The problem I have right now is the drawing seems to only draw the visible area. When I scroll, everything outside of the currently visible area is blank. If I change the width of viewA in the storyboard to 1200, then it will draw the entire canvas. I want to set the width of viewA programmatically. I can't figure out why `drawRect` won't draw outside.

Both scroll view and viewA are created from the storyboard (288x300). The initWithCoder looks like (got scrollView and viewA from IBOutlet):

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    viewA.frame = CGRectMake(viewA.frame.origin.x, viewA.frame.origin.y, 1200, viewA.frame.size.height);
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1200, viewA.frame.size.height);
}
```

In the drewRect of viewA view class, I draw some vertical lines.

If I set the width of viewA to 1200 from IB, then all vertical lines are drawn. But if I changed the width of viewA from initWithCoder, then only part of the lines are drawn.

In fact, I changed my design by creating both views programmatically and no longer have this issue, but I would love to learn why this is not working.

[image]

Comment: What to you want to do exactly? Also whose frame.size.width is set to 1200?

Comment: @blancos I want to drawRect to draw the entire scroll view content. As it is right now, it only draws the visible area, but not outside.

Comment: Ok then first of all update your question and clearly mention the dimensions of both views. Also try to paste some corresponding code if possible.

Comment: Darn. My Situation exactly, but really the question should be written out without the footnote, and your answer equally written out with code as a proper discrete supply.